# No such Column error when trying to execute two conditions using where

Tags: database, count, android-sqlite, multiple-columns

I am newbie to android development.In my project I am trying to get the count of number of rows using following query.I got (1)No such column:column_name error.This is my logcat,

```
no such column: userid (code 1): , while compiling: select count(*) from Messages where userid = userr AND  statusy = status
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
 12-18 12:48:13.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1372):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
```

This is my table creation statement,

```
 String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "(" + KEY_USERID + " TEXT," + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FROM + " TEXT," + KEY_TO + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BODY + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
```

And this is my query,

```
   public int Get_Total_Contacts() {


        String countQuery="select count(*) from " + TABLE_MESSAGES + " where " + KEY_USERID + " = userr AND  " + KEY_STATUS + " = status";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

            int a=cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();

    return a;

    }
```

Can anyone help me where I made mistake?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Textual data must be quoted.

Comment: yeaah its already quoted..

Comment: It is not in query. See Nizam answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String countQuery="select count(*) from " + TABLE_MESSAGES + " where " + KEY_USERID + " = 'userr' AND  " + KEY_STATUS + " = 'status'";
```

Be aware with each space and quote when using rawquery.

The exception says that there is no such column named 'userid' in the table 'Messages'. I hope you made an insertion before, which is successful. after insertion, pull the db file from the device(can use DDMS) and browse the table to check whether it is ok.

Most of the time, we get 'No such column' error because of spelling mistakes or wrong structured table. In your case, may be the second one.

Comment: your query is right but i got the wrong result.It always returns 1 as the count value